# How to implement notification system in react native with wordpress backend

Tags: wordpress, react-native, expo

I'm trying to implement a notification system in my expo react native project using wordpress as the backend. Expo provide a simple way to do push notification which only require the server to call expo's push notification api with user's device token and expo will handle the rest.
My guess is to build a custom wordpress plugin which can be used inside wordpress's admin page. If this is the case, how do i proceed to do this and are there any alternatives?

Answer (score 1):

You could use some external providers like Firebase or Parse Server (i.e. Back4App). Both support push notifications and both provide API which you should be able to call from your back-end.